# Matrix manipulation to get a vetor

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let say I have a matrix $X^{P \times n}$ and another square matrix $A^{n \times n}$. Now the dimension of the multiplication $X \times A \times X'$ will be $P \times P$.

Now I want to extract each row of $X$ with this a vector of length $n$, let say this $x_i$. Now I want to perform ${x_i} \times A \times {x_i}'$. This will be a scalar. Now I can run a loop for all rows of $X$ and resultingly will get a matrix of dimension $P \times 1$.

Is there any way to perform above calculation using matrix multiplication?

Comment: Hint : Multiplying the transpose of $X$ with the column vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\ \vdots\\ 0\\  1\\0\\ \vdots\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ gives you the $i$-th row of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Could you please say little more how such construct can avoid a loop which I am using?

Comment: When I hear "avoid a loop" I suspect it is a programming question. Off topic here.

Comment: Okay. You can then replace the word `loop` with `element by element` calculation

Comment: A matrix multiplication is by definition an element by element calculation. If you want to formulate a mathematical problem we obviously need a lot more background.

Comment: BTW . In python it is very simple to set up a few loops that pretty much do everything you want.

Comment: Please forget loop etc. I just want to formulate my multiplication as a problem of matrix multiplication which is hoped to be more concise than just what I am doing currently (as stated in my post)

Comment: Ok. In that case do the matrix multiplication $X^\top\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\ \vdots\\ 0\\  1\\0\\ \vdots\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ which gives you $x_i$ (the $i$-th row vector of $X$). Then do the matrix multiplication $x_i^\top A x_i$ . I might have another understanding of row- or column vectors but (as we know) the matrix multiplication will work if and only if they fit.

Comment: Thanks. But even with this, I still need to repeat this for each row individually right?